# Run two JMX ManagedOperations in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, jmx

I've got simple class for running certain job using jmx. I want to implement the functionality to start and stop this job (it may run for a long time). Something like this:

```
@Component
@ManagedResource
public class JobRunner
{
    private static boolean stopped = false;

    @ManagedOperation
    public void start()
    {
        stopped = false;
        while (!stopped)
        {
             // Some actions..
        }
    }

    @ManagedOperation
    public void stop()
    {
        stopped = true;
    }

}
```

Have no ideas how to make it work. How to make these methods run independently in parallel streams and make method stop() influence on the loop inside start().

Answer (score 0):

A few suggestions:

1. Use an AtomicBoolean to track if the job is running.
2. Launch the job in a thread so it runs in the background and not in the JMX thread (otherwise the JMX invocation to start the job will block).
3. The job thread should occasionally pause so it can be interrupted when stopped.

Simple Example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;
import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedOperation;
import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ManagedResource
public class JobRunner
{
    private final AtomicBoolean stopped = new AtomicBoolean(true);
    private Thread jobThread = null;



    @ManagedOperation
    public void start() {
        if(stopped.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
          jobThread = new Thread("JobThread") {
            public void run() {
              while(!stopped.get()) {
                // Some actions..

                // Occassionally pause so the job can be interrupted
                try {
                  Thread.currentThread().join(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException iex) {
                  if(!stopped.get()) {
                    System.err.println("Job Thread was interrupted but not stopped");
                    JobRunner.this.stop();
                    break;
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          };
          jobThread.setDaemon(true); // Optional
          jobThread.start();
        } else {
          throw new IllegalStateException("Job was already running");
        }
    }

    @ManagedOperation
    public void stop() {
        if(stopped.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
          jobThread.interrupt();
          jobThread = null;
        } else {
          throw new IllegalStateException("Job was not running");
        }
    }
}
```